# Compare two XML using XMLUnit by skipping few attributes of some TAGs

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I'm working on this java API(XMLUuit.jar) from last few days.
I want to compare two XML files by skipping few parameters of a XML tag using XMLUnit API.

```xml
<emp>
  <name id="1">xyz</name>
</emp>
```

```xml
<emp>
  <name id="2">xyz</name>
</emp>
```

these two files are same if i skip the comparison of id attribute.
i have some scenarios where requirements are like this.
Any suggestions ????

Answer (score 0):

In order to suppress certain differences you implement a `DifferenceEvaluator`

```
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.xmlunit.builder.DiffBuilder;
import org.xmlunit.diff.*;
import org.xmlunit.util.Nodes;

public class AttributesTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Diff d = DiffBuilder.compare("<emp>\n" +
                                     "  <name id=\"1\">xyz</name>\n" +
                                     "</emp>")
            .withTest("<emp>\n" +
                      "  <name id=\"2\">xyz</name>\n" +
                      "</emp>")
            .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byName))
            .withDifferenceEvaluator((comparison, outcome) -> {
                    if (outcome != ComparisonResult.EQUAL && comparison.getType() == ComparisonType.ATTR_VALUE) {
                        Attr a = (Attr) comparison.getControlDetails().getTarget();
                        if ("id".equals(Nodes.getQName(a).getLocalPart())
                            && "name".equals(Nodes.getQName(a.getOwnerElement()).getLocalPart())) {
                            return ComparisonResult.EQUAL;
                        }
                    }
                    return outcome;
                })
            .build();
        System.err.println("Differences? " + d.hasDifferences());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello sir,
Jar i'm using is not having this folder structure and "DiffBuilder" class is also not present in JAR.
Can you provide link form where i can get this JAR file??
Thanks

Comment: You are probably using XMLUnit 1.x rather than 2.x. See http://www.xmlunit.org/ or https://github.com/xmlunit/xmlunitfor detaiils on 2.x.